# Laravel join query with sum

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
SELECT 
    users.name,
    SUM(mileages.mileage) as mileage,
    mileages.date 
FROM users INNER JOIN mileages ON users.id=mileages.user_id 
GROUP BY users.name
```

Could you please help me to convert this mysql query in Laravel query build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('mileages','users.id','=','mileages.user_id')
    ->select('users.name',DB::raw('SUM(mileages.mileage) as mileage),'mileages.date')
    ->get();
```

should do the magic.
Didn't try it, just copied from laravel docs.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MySql 'view' to resolve this problem

CREATE VIEW view_name AS
select `b`.`name` AS `name`,
sum(`a`.`mileage`) AS `mileage` 
from(`prudential`.`mileages` `a` 
join `prudential`.`users` `b` 
on((`a`.`user_id` = `b`.`id`)))
where((year(`a`.`date`) = year(curdate())) 
and(month(`a`.`date`) = month(curdate()))) 
group by `b`.`name`

Comment: And what about your query used Laravel query builder?Furthermore, you are adding now a where-clause in your query. Do you still ne a Laravel query builder-Query?